# Entity Framework Inefficient generated queries with includes and order bys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

1) First issue I'm having is if you do an include and then an order by the SQL generated generates an inner join and an outer join

```
var query = from l in Lead.Include("Contact")
orderby l.Contact.FirstName
select l;
```

Which generates the following inner join and outer join on the same table

```
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[Contact] AS [Extent2] 
      ON [Extent1].[ContactId] = [Extent2].[ContactId]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Contact] AS [Extent3] 
      ON [Extent1].[ContactId] = [Extent3]. [ContactId]
ORDER BY [Extent2].[FirstName] ASC
```

Which makes for a slightly inefficient query

2) if I do multiple includes it always does the second one as an outer join so like

```
 Lead.Include("OneToOne").Include("OtherOneToOne") <- in this scenario     
                                                      OtherOneToOne is an outer 
                                                     join and OneToOne is an inner 
                                                     join
 Lead.Include("OtherOneToOne").Include("OneToOne") <- in this scenario 
                                                      OneToOne is an outer join 
                                                      and OtherOneToOne is an 
                                                      inner join
```

is that just how it works?

I found another post where someone was talking about this and they said that it was fixed in the June CTP release
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx

But I installed and setup that to be used and it still doesn't work..

alright it won't let me answer my own question

so

**EDIT:**
Alright I setup an isolated test and found that http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx  seems to have resolved these

But since I'm using RIA I'm out of luck since the june ctp doesn't support RIA :-/

Comment: Hmmm actually I don't think I set it up right to use the ctp ..... It doesn't seem to be playing well with RIA.... Lets see....

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to do the include yourself:

```
var query = from l in Lead
select new { l, l.Contact } into row
orderby row.Contact.FirstName
select row;
```